# Installing a downloaded driver

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, adapter

I recently downloaded the driver for my TP Link Ethernet Adapter. It is in the .tar format. However, being new to Ubuntu, I have no idea how to manually install downloaded driver.
Also, the adapter has plug and play support and earlier it used to work without any drivers but it stopped working a while back and shows nothing in installed drivers. Any input on that?

Edit-
Running **lsusb** on the terminal -

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2357:0601  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3526 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5a07 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:0941 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Driver [link](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-usb-3-0-software)

Edit2-

**lsmod | grep -e cdc -e r81**

```
cdc_ether              20480  0
usbnet                 45056  1 cdc_ether
r8152                  65536  0
mii                    16384  2 usbnet,r8152
```

**modinfo r8152 | grep 0601**

```
alias:          usb:v2357p0601d*dc*dsc*dp*ic02isc06ip00in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0601d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc*ip*in*
```

**ip l**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:c5:d3:9f:b2:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: enx503eaa292ae3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:3e:aa:29:2a:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Edit2-

**ip a**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:c5:d3:9f:b2:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: enx503eaa292ae3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:3e:aa:29:2a:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.100/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx503eaa292ae3
       valid_lft 19sec preferred_lft 19sec
    inet6 fe80::5cb1:ab0:a367:974c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**ip r**

```
default via 192.168.2.1 dev enx503eaa292ae3 proto dhcp metric 20100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enx503eaa292ae3 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.2.0/24 dev enx503eaa292ae3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.100 metric 100
```

**ping -c3 8.8.8.8**

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

**ls -al /etc/resolv.conf**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Aug 10 19:24 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

**dmesg | grep enx**

```
[   13.633275] r8152 2-1:1.0 enx503eaa292ae3: renamed from eth0
[   19.983226] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx503eaa292ae3: link becomes ready
[   19.983508] r8152 2-1:1.0 enx503eaa292ae3: carrier on
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101321/discussion-on-question-by-grv-installing-a-downloaded-driver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue finally.

Appears that due to some reason, IP was not being assigned to the ethernet connection despite being connected. So I followed the instructions on [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297046). Since the ethernet connection was working perfectly with windows, I copied the IPv4 address, netmask and default gateway from windows and used in Ubuntu. Works (though not sure if this is a permanent solution).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the problem here is a lack of drivers, but rather a lack of configuration of the network connection.

Press the arrow in the top of your screen, select the Wired connection, and press connect. This should activate the connection.

[image]

Comment: I am getting it as connected with a question mark https://imgur.com/a/q3GRh73

Comment: Update your question with the output of `ip a` and `ip r`

Comment: edited the question